# If I flag my own question asking a moderator if it should be migrated, will i get penalized?

Tags: support

I have asked a question on SO which may be more appropriate for the dba site.

If I flag my own question asking a moderator if maybe it should be moved, will I be penalized some how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's always a risk that your flag is declined and you lose some flag weight (roughly analogous to throwing some monopoly dollars into the fireplace), but it shouldn't be, *if your question is on-topic for the target site.*

Comment: Uh oh… I didn't know this. What is the exchange between Monopoly dollars and USA dollars? `:-)`

Comment: *This coupon's cash value is .01 cents.*

Comment: @kiamlaluno [~1103 MPD : 1 USD](http://www.amazon.com/Hasbro-Monopoly-Money/dp/B00000IWCW)